# prettyPhoto in IE not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Any ideas why this shows the gallery as it should in FF but not in IE?

In Firefox, when a picture is clicked, the prettyPhoto overlay comes up and you can navigate the gallery. However, in IE, it just shows the picture on a separate window...

Comment: what version of IE?... works for me.

Comment: Any IE... Doesn't work on my computer!

Comment: It works for me in IE.  Try:  (1) Shutdown IE, (2) Run [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER), (3) try again.  If that doesn't work, reboot.  Then try a clean IE install and/or another computer.

Comment: It works fine in my IE 8

Answer (score 6):

The IE you're using might have JavaScript disabled. If I disable JavaScript on Firefox, the site acts (almost) as you've described: clicking on a picture opens it on a new page.

Follow the instructions here to enable JavaScript: https://superuser.com/questions/246803/internet-explorer-8-9-javascript-disable-need-to-enable-back

Answer (score 1):

Just be keep in mind that when doing some scripting ,check if there's an error beneath each of the ie browsers and when you do you can correct this inorder to make the plugins works perfectly fine.

and by the way I've noticed that your website loading of images is so slow due to oversize height and width .i would suggest that you can use lazy load inorder to optimize fast connection to your website.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with IE8 and prettyphoto 3.1.3.
Set deeplink: false and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has to do with the way that IE is handling the prettyPhoto script. PrettyPhoto seems to be doing a url request to load the photo which is causing a page refresh – perhaps a setting you have in your version of IE defaults to opening links in new windows.

It's completely unnecessary to redirect for a lightbox to browse a gallery. Perhaps a cleaner script for you would be jQuery Tools' Overlay ( http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html ), which gives you the ability to customize your content output within the overlay without a URL change.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add border:none style rule to your image within links.

```
a img {border:none;}
```

Comment: that doesn't do anything... in Firefox when you click on a picture it comes up as an overlay, but not in IE...

Comment: when I saw the page in IE, I saw two pictures in a row and then the third one in the second row. I also notices the images had blue borders around them in IE. so I added the above style to the style sheet and then the result was similar to one in Firefox. Remember that the browser caches the stylesheet, so you should do a complete refresh of the page in the browser (Ctrl + F5) for the new stylesheet to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am not talking about the stylesheet, I am talking about prettyPhoto. If you click on a picture in Firefox you'll see that it opens as an overlay and can be navigated. However, you cannot do that in IE, it's a jquery problem...

Comment: Technically it's not a jQuery problem, but a problem with prettyPhoto itself. It's a matter of the way it's handling the overlay by amending `!#prettyPhoto[gallery1]/X/` to the URL.